# wordpress website inner pages showing 404 on amazon EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

EC2 server, i create a WordPress website and move it on amazon server. only home page is working, when i click on other pages (like, about us) it's showing 404 error. if i  set about us page as home page from admin panel, it is showing it content.

http://52.32.194.58/